# k&r exercise confusion with bit-operations

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, kr-c

The exercise is:
Write a function setbits(x,p,n,y) that returns x with the n bits that begin at position p set to the rightmost n bits of y, leaving the other bits unchanged.

My attempt at a solution is:

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned setbits(unsigned, int, int, unsigned);

int main(void)
{
    printf("%u\n", setbits(256, 4, 2, 255));
    return 0;
}

unsigned setbits(unsigned x, int p, int n, unsigned y)
{
    return (x >> (p + 1 - n)) | (1 << (n & y));
}
```

It's probably incorrect, but am I on the right path here? If not, what am I doing wrong? I'm unsure as to why I don't perfectly understand this, but I spent about an hour trying to come up with this.

Thanks.

Comment: exactly the same question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1415854/kr-c-exercise-help

Comment: Question about the same K&R problem - the explanations there might help.  But not quite the same question; svr here has made an effort to provide code.

Comment: @Jonathan, I agree. That's why I didn't vote to close it.

Answer (score 5):

Here's your algorithm:

1. If n is 0, return x.
2. Take 1, and left shift it n times and then subtract 1. Call this `mask`.
3. Left shift mask p times call this `mask2`.
4. `And` x with the inverse of mask2. `And` y with mask, and left shift p times.
5. `Or` the results of those two operations, and return that value.

Comment: Like so: unsigned setbits(unsigned x, int p, int n, unsigned y) { int mask = (1 << n - 1) - 1; int nask = (mask << p); if (!n) return x; return ((x | ~(nask)) | ((y & mask) << p)); }

?

Comment: Looks better than the answers I got before :) 

unsigned setbits(unsigned x, int p, int n, unsigned y) { int mask = (1 << n - 1) - 1; int nask = (mask << p); if (!n) return x; return ((x & ~(nask)) | ((y & mask) << p)); }

Thanks

Comment: You are correct about the subtraction/shifting so I'll fix that. But "position" in binary starts at the right with 0 and increments left.

Comment: I took "n bits starting at p" to mean "starting at bit position p, and going n-1 bits 'to the right'".  Looks like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1415854/kr-c-exercise-help agrees with me.

Answer (score 3):

I think the answer is a slightly modified application of the getbits example from section 2.9.

Lets break it down as follows:

```
Let bitstring x be 1 0 1 1 0 0
Let bitstring y be 1 0 1 1 1 1

positions -------->5 4 3 2 1 0
```

Setting `p = 4 and n =3` gives us the bitstring from x which is `0 1 1`. It starts at 4 and ends at 2 and spans 3 elements.

What we want to do is to replace `0 1 1` with `1 1 1`(the last three elements of bitstring y).

Lets forget about left-shift/right-shift for the moment and visualize the problem as follows:

We need to grab the last three digits from bitstring y which is `1 1 1`

Place `1 1 1` directly under positions `4 3 and 2` of bitstring x.

Replace `0 1 1` with `1 1 1` while keeping the rest of the bits intact...

Now lets go into a little more detail...

My first statement was:

```
We need to grab the last three digits from bitstring y which is 1 1 1
```

The way to isolate bits from a bitstring is to first start with bitstring that has all 0s.
We end up with `0 0 0 0 0 0`.

0s have this incredible property where bitwise '&'ing it with another number gives us all 0s and bitwise '|'ing it with another number gives us back that other number.

0 by itself is of no use here...but it tells us that if we '|' the last three digits of y with a '0', we will end up with 1 1 1. The other bits in y don't really concern us here, so we need to figure out a way to zero out those numbers while keeping the last three digits intact. In essence we need the number `0 0 0 1 1 1`.

So lets look at the series of transformations required:

```
Start with  ->  0 0 0 0 0 0
apply ~0    ->  1 1 1 1 1 1
lshift by 3 ->  1 1 1 0 0 0 
apply ~     ->  0 0 0 1 1 1
& with y    ->  0 0 0 1 1 1 & 1 0 1 1 1 1 -> 0 0 0 1 1 1
```

And this way we have the last three digits to be used for setting purposes...

My second statement was:

> Place 1 1 1 directly under positions 4 3 and 2 of bitstring x.

A hint for doing this can be found from the getbits example in section 2.9. What we know about positions 4,3 and 2, can be found from the values `p = 4 and n =3`. p is the position and n is the length of the bitset. Turns out `p+1-n` gives us the offset of the bitset from the rightmost bit. In this particular example `p+1-n = 4 +1-3 = 2`.

So..if we do a left shift by 2 on the string `0 0 0 1 1 1`, we end up with `0 1 1 1 0 0`. If you put this string under x, you will notice that `1 1 1` aligns with positions `4 3 and 2` of x.

I think I am finally getting somewhere...the last statement I made was..

> Replace 0 1 1 with 1 1 1 while keeping the rest of the bits intact...

Lets review our strings now:

```
x           ->   1 0 1 1 0 0
isolated y  ->   0 1 1 1 0 0
```

Doing a bitwise or on these two values gives us what we need for this case:

```
1 1 1 1 0 0
```

But this would fail if instead of `1 1 1`, we had `1 0 1`...so if we need to dig a little more to get to our "silver-bullet"...

Lets look at the above two strings one more time...

```
x -> bit by bit...1(stays) 0(changes) 1(changes) 1(changes) 0(stays) 0(stays)
```

So ideally..we need the bitstring `1 x x x 0 0`, where the x's will be swapped with 1's.
Here's a leap of intuition that will help us..

```
Bitwise complement of isolated y -> 1 0 0 0 1 1
& this with x gives us           -> 1 0 0 0 0 0
| this with isolated y           -> 1 1 1 1 0 0 (TADA!)
```

Hope this long post helps people with rationalizing and solving such bitmasking problems...

Thanks

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful, as none of the other answers really _explained_ what was happening.

Comment: It was the best. Had to spent 5min to login & upvote. I had issues understanding the exercise itself and your explaining is wonderful

Answer (score 0):

Note that `~0 << i` gives you a number with the least significant `i` bits set to `0`, and the rest of the bits set to `1`.  Similarly, `~(~0 << i)` gives you a number with the least significant `i` bits set to `1`, and the rest to `0`.

Now, to solve your problem:

1. First, you want a number that has all the bits except the `n` bits that begin at position `p` set to the bits of `x`.  For this, you need a mask that comprises of `1` in all the places except the `n` bits beginning at position `p`:

   1. this mask has the topmost (most significant) bits set, starting with the bit at position `p+1`.
   2. this mask also has the least significant `p+1-n` bits set.
2. Once you have the above mask, `&` of this mask with `x` will give you the number you wanted in step 1.
3. Now, you want a number that has the least significant `n` bits of `y` set, shifted left `p+1-n` bits.

   1. You can easily make a mask that has only the least significant `n` bits set, and `&` it with `y` to extract `y`'s least significant `n` bits.
   2. Then, you can shift this number by `p+1-n` bits.
4. Finally, you can bitwise-or (`|`) the results of step 2 and 3.2 to get your number.

Clear as mud? :-)

(The above method should be independent of the size of the numbers, which I think is important.)

*Edit*: looking at your effort: `n & y` doesn't do anything with `n` bits.  For example, if `n` is 8, you want the last 8 bits of `y`, but `n & y` will just pick the 4th bit of `y` (8 in binary is 1000).  So you know that can't be right.  Similarly, right-shifting `x` `p+1-n` times gives you a number that has the most significant `p+1-n` bits set to zero and the rest of the bits are made of the most significant bits of `x`.  This isn't what you want either.